# How to boot from USB on Sony Vaio PCG-TR3S?

Tags: boot, bios, usb-flash-drive, google-chrome-os

I have an old Sony Vaio PCG-TR3S that isn't running very well any more. It crashes a lot.

I heard of Chromium OS Vanilla and decided to try running that on my old laptop by booting from a USB stick, but unfortunately it doesn't have USB as a boot option in BIOS.

Is there a way that I can get the laptop to boot from USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the [Plop Boot Mananger](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager.html) does what I need. I was able to create a bootable CD with **Plop Boot Manager** installed. When it runs, it prompts me which device to boot from, which includes USB.

Comment: So even though I was able to boot from USB, turns out Chromium won't run on my laptop. It needs PAE instruction support which isn't included on the old Pentium M CPU. I was able to use xPUD instead, which seems to be a nice reliable minimal OS which I can put on a small USB flash drive.

Comment: There's too many people in this conversation, I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

In Rufus the default settings are GPT but with FAT32(Default). But sony vaio BIOS support MBR with NTFS, When bootable pen drive using RUFUS change settings. Keep this in mind! otherwise, you’re gonna have a bad time.